# How to convert DataSet into Dictionary in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, wcf

My WCF service function return type is Dictionary(Of String, String). So I have to convert my Dataset to Dictionary.

Here is my dataset example.

Account     AccountNames

abc           abc1

abc           abc2

abc            abc3

xyz           xyz1

xyz             xyz2

xyz           xyz3

xyz            xyz4

pqr            pqr1

pqr           pqr2

pqr           pqr3

pqr           pqr4

pqr           pqr5

pqr           pqr6

Using LINQ or without LINQ, How can I convert Dataset To  Dictionary(Of String,  String)

Regards,
RN

Comment: If the first column is the the key and the left column is the value, you're going to have multiple values for each key - which will defeat the purpose of a dictionary, I think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the 2nd column are the keys you can do this:

```
Dim ds As DataSet = someValueHere
Dim dc As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
For Each r As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
     dc.Add(r.Item(1).ToString(), r.Item(0).ToString())
Next
```

I don't know if there will be a shortcut for linq.
Note: dictionary cannot contain duplicate keys, so if the 1st column corresponds the key and the 2nd column for the values, it is not possible.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a few options using LINQ.

The most direct "one-liner" is:

```
Dim dictionary =
    ds.Tables(0).Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)() _
        .ToDictionary(Function (dr) dr.Field(Of String)(0), _
            Function (dr) dr.Field(Of String)(1))
```

I think the VB.NET lamdba syntax is a little ugly so I like to pull them out like this:

```
Dim fk As Func(Of DataRow, String) = Function (dr) dr.Field(Of String)(0)
Dim fv As Func(Of DataRow, String) = Function (dr) dr.Field(Of String)(1)

Dim dictionary = ds.Tables(0).Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)().ToDictionary(fk, fv)
```

That might even be too ugly, so this is an option:

```
Dim fn as Func(Of Integer, Func(Of DataRow, String)) = _
    Function (n) _
        Function (dr) _
            dr.Field(Of String)(n)

Dim dictionary = ds.Tables(0).Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)().ToDictionary(fn(0), fn(1))
```

Or even by column name:

```
Dim fs as Func(Of String, Func(Of DataRow, String)) = _
    Function (s) _
        Function (dr) _
            dr.Field(Of String)(s)

Dim dictionary =
    ds.Tables(0).Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)() _
        .ToDictionary(fs("AccountName"), fs("Account"))
```

I hope these help.

Comment: +1 for multiple options with the LINQ syntax.  VB.NET and LINQ gives me a headache, but then I'm mainly a C# person :)

Comment: @Tim - I agree about VB.NET and LINQ. If only C# had XML literals I'd be stoked!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example with LINQ, using the same assumption that jerjer's answer had (that the 2nd column are the keys):

```
Dim dict As Dictionary(Of string, string) = (From a In ds.Tables(0).AsEnumerable()
                                            Select New With
                                            {
                                                .Key = a.Field(Of String)("AccountName"),
                                                .Val = a.Field(Of String)("Account")
                                            }).AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(Function(k) k.Key, Function(v) v.Val)
```

The syntax may be a bit off, as I don't do VB.NET that much, but that should give you the general idea.

Comment: Thank u TIM, THIS IS ALSO HELPING ME.